# Map to os.rename multiple files

Tags: python-3.x

I have such a program

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
import os
import glob
import copy

fs = os.listdir()
fs = filter(lambda x: not x.endswith("org"), fs)
fsc = copy.deepcopy(fs)
print(list(fsc)[:5])
# map(lambda x: os.rename(x, f"{x}.org"), fs)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: ['19.Pseudo-Terminals', '12.Thread-Control', '05.Standard-IO-Library', '07.Process-Environment', '03.File-IO']
```

Later, add org to the names

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
map(lambda x: os.rename(x, x+'.org'), fs)
! ls | head -n 5
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 00.Preface.org
: 01.UNIX-System-Overvie
: 01.xhtml
: 02.UNIX-Standardization-and-Implementations
: 03.File-IO
```

It did not work, thus for loop works

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
for f in fs:
    os.rename(f, f"{f}.org")
! ls | head -n 5
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 00.Preface.org
: 01.UNIX-System-Overview.org
: 01.xhtml.org
: 02.UNIX-Standardization-and-Implementations.org
: 03.File-IO.org
```

Leave alone that python does not appreciate functional programming, what the reason `map` does not work?

Comment: You need to consume the iterator returned by map. Try `list(map(...))`.

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @JustinEzequiel

Answer (score 2):

You need to consume the iterator returned by map. Try

```
list(map(lambda x: os.rename(x, x+'.org'), fs))
```